# Finding a specify Org-mode Color Theme

Tags: themes

I've been searching for a while the following org-mode color theme on the net, which replace asterisk by circle, but I can't find it.

Anyone happens to know the name of this theme?

Thanks

[image: circle org mode]

Comment: Please consider accepting one of the answers below.

Answer (score 10):

Not sure of the specific colors, but to replace the asterisks with custom unicode chars, you might use https://github.com/sabof/org-bullets

Answer (score 8):

Doesn't sound like a theme to be honest.

Try [org-bullet](https://github.com/sabof/org-bullets).